# Updating RStudio in Linux (Google Chromebook)

Tags: r, linux, rstudio, chromebook

I am trying to update RStudio on my Google Chromebook (running on Linux) and it is not working. Does anyone have some code I could use in the Linux terminal to update my RStudio?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably the best way is to download and install RStudio from scratch.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion for a website that explains this step-by-step? I tried doing this but something always seems to go wrong, which made me think I am missing some part of the code :/

Comment: It depends on on what Linux distribution you have on your Chromebook. What error do you get? Have you tried to google for "rstudio chrome_os"?